# Unable to Active Xenserver Free License

Tags: xenserver

I have recently installed Xenserver 6.5 onto a local development server for testing. I wanted to active using the free license from Citrix but seem unable to.

When I navigate to the License Manager dialog, I can see the "Active Free XenServer" button.

[image: xenserver_error1]

But when I select the dev-xenserver-01 the "Active Free License" box disappears.

[image: xenserver_error2]

Does anyone know why this is happening, I assume you can active a free license for a 2 socket machine, I've seen mentions of a free trail. Am I still in that period and need to wait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XenServer 6.2 and 6.5 do not require any license to use the free version: you can use all free features without activation.

The "Activate Free XenServer" button in XenCenter dates from versions prior to 6.2, where you *did* need to re-request a license each year for the free edition. Because XenCenter can be used with older versions of XenServer, the button remains (confusingly!).

If you want to try out the *premium* features of 6.5, you'll need an Enterprise Edition trial license, available from https://www.citrix.com/products/xenserver/try.html .

XenServer 6.5 comes in three editions: Free, Standard (same features as Free, but with Citrix support), and Enterprise (premium features, and support). You can find a feature matrix at http://support.citrix.com/content/dam/supportWS/kA460000000CmyyCAC/XenServer_6.5_Feature_Matrix.pdf .

Cheers,

David Cottingham

XenServer Product Management, Citrix.

Comment: XenServer 7 is asking for a License server URL in port :27000, can you tell us please which is the URL ?

Comment: That's really a separate question, but in short, the URL is of the Citrix license server that you've deployed somewhere in your environment.